# Why does Xamarin.FFImageLoading SVG is not working on Android 11 & 12?

Tags: android, xamarin, svg, ffimageloading

Xamarin.FFImageLoading SVG seems to not be working on Android 11 & 12.

For example, when I do Android Target to 11 Version, setting the SVG on Embedded Resource, with this code:

```xml
<ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage HeightRequest="12" Source="resource://DemoApp.Assets.Images.svgImage.svg" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Aspect="Fill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
```

This SVG works fine except on Android 11 & 12.

Could anyone please help to figure out why it's not showing on Android 11 & 12?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that it's a special issue on the Android 11, and the solution is add the reference of the skiasharp or update the nuget package skiasharp both in the android part and the forms part.

You can check the following link:https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/1526

Comment: Thanks for Ur Valuable Answer .. i will try this method and will ping to status..

Comment: Glad to help you and more detail is in the link I provided. @udayasankar

Comment: Thanks @iyun-zhang for given solution working for me...
and also i have one more issue on CarouselViewControl ..Could You Help Me?

Comment: I'm sorry for late reply. I don't have a ios device and I'm not good at ios.@udayasankar